# Tkinter: Inserting data using grid()?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I've been having an issue with Tkinter and inserting data into a gui built using `grid()`. I've noticed that the topic of inserting data using `.pack()` is pretty prevalent.

My question is if this is on purpose? Is it not possible to insert data into an entry widget if it is not packed?

I believe it would fairly valuable if someone could provide an explanation.

Here is the code for `pack()`:

```
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, "a default value")
```

Comment: _"I believe it would fairly valuable if someone could provide an explanation."_ - explanation of what? You're asking about `grid` but haven't showed how you're trying to use `grid`. There's nothing preventing you from calling `insert` whether you're using `pack`, `place`, `grid`, or anything else.

Comment: You can control the location of widgets with `grid()`. Here's a little [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190521203213id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html). You can also insert data in some widgets such as an `Entry`. Here some [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530085656id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about `grid` that would prevent you from inserting data into an `Entry` widget. Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
entry.insert(0, "Hello, world")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you put your entry in the grid in the same line that initiate it, your entry will have "NoneType" and you can't use the entry.insert() method. If you need to insert text into an entry widget, do something like this:

```
    root=Tk()
    ent=Entry(root)
    ent.grid(row=0,column=0)
    ent.insert(0,"Hellow World")
    root.mainloop()
```